How to Implement Checkbox Selection in ABP Angular UI for IdentityComponents
I'm seeking to implement checkbox selection within ABP Angular's IdentityComponents. Specifically, I need the ability to select individual rows or all rows for export purposes. How can I achieve this functionality using the built-in components provided by ABP Angular IdentityComponents?
If anyone has experience or advice on integrating checkbox selection into these components, I would greatly appreciate your insights. Thank you!
I have thoroughly reviewed the ABP documentation but haven't found a suitable solution for implementing checkbox selection.
